# How to update form element data value after construction using multidict

Tags: python, validation, wtforms

I have a website post creator / editor im writing. I have successfully been able to create post (saves to json) , get a pull down menu list of the made post from same db (and a second, all posts.json, which is where the list of posts comes from. ), and have the element forms populated with said information. I can then save it, and it is indeed writing to the file. Problem is , the data in the text fields is not updating in saved post. It saves the original data passed with the multidict. I CAN manually update it as : Ex.  form.title.data = "New Title" , and it saves as such, so i know its handling everything correctly on the save end. If anyone has an idea how to get the updated information from the form fields, id be grateful. Thank you.

Constructors at line 103
Code: 
https://hastebin.com/lafavifike.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for
from QFlask import QFlask
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from wtforms.fields import Field, TextAreaField, TextField, SelectField
from wtforms.widgets import TextArea
import os, json
from werkzeug.datastructures import MultiDict

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "test"

class editPostForm(FlaskForm):
    id_pos = ['blog_posts', 'security_posts', 'game_posts','music_posts','project_posts']
    file_path_all = str(os.getcwd()) + "\\static\\allposts.json"
    with open(file_path_all, 'r') as post_edit:
            all_posts = json.load(post_edit)
            posts = [('default', 'Choose Post To Edit')]
            for key in all_posts.keys():
                if key not in id_pos:
                    posts.append((all_posts[key]['id'], all_posts[key]['title']))
    loadform = SelectField('Choose Post', choices=posts)
    loadposts = SubmitField('Load')

class PostForm(FlaskForm): 
    #Actual form fields     
    categories = [('blog_posts','Blog Post'), ('security_posts','Security Post'),('game_posts','Games Post'),('music_posts','Music Post'),('project_posts','Projects Post')]
    category = SelectField('Category', choices = categories, validators = [DataRequired()])
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    date = StringField('Date', validators=[DataRequired()])
    content = TextAreaField('Content', validators=[DataRequired()], widget=TextArea())
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    file_path = str(os.getcwd()) + "\\static\\posts.json"
    with open(file_path, 'r+') as post_edit:
        data = json.load(post_edit)
        positions = {}
        for key in data['id_pos'].keys():
            positions[key] = data['id_pos'][key]

    #Create Post Form
    prefixs = {'1':'blog_posts','2':'security_posts',"3":"game_posts","4":"music_posts","5":"project_posts"}
    form = PostForm()
    edit_form = editPostForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(edit_form.loadform.data)
        if edit_form.loadform.data != 'None':
            return redirect('/edit_post/'+ edit_form.loadform.data)
        else:
            form.validate()
            category = form.category.data
            title = form.title.data
            date = form.date.data
            content = form.content.data
            post_id = str(int(positions[category]) +1)
            post = {
                "id": post_id,
                "title": title,
                "date": date,
                "content": content
            }

            #Update data structure, and save back to the file
            data['id_pos'][category] = post_id
            data[category][post_id] = post
            #SAVE POST
            data['index_posts'][post_id] = post
            with open(file_path, 'w') as post_edit:
                json.dump(data, post_edit)
                print('Post Saved')
                flash('Post Saved')
            file_path_all = str(os.getcwd()) + "\\static\\allposts.json"
            with open(file_path_all, 'r+') as file:
                data = json.load(file)
            with open(file_path_all, 'w') as file:
                data[post_id] = post
                json.dump(data, file)
            return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('post_editor.html', title="Post Creator", form=form, edit_form = edit_form)

@app.route('/edit_post/<id>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def edit_post(id):
    #Load data from JSON Files. posts= categorized posts, allposts is all posts key'd by id.
    file_path_all = str(os.getcwd()) + "\\static\\allposts.json"
    file_path = str(os.getcwd()) + "\\static\\posts.json"
    with open(file_path, 'r+') as post_edit:
        data = json.load(post_edit)
    with open(file_path_all, 'r') as post_edit:
        all_posts = json.load(post_edit)
        posts = [('default', 'Choose Post To Edit')]
        for key in all_posts.keys():
            posts.append((all_posts[key]['id'], all_posts[key]['title']))

    #Auto filling category and data for fields
    prefixs = {'1':'blog_posts','2':'security_posts',"3":"game_posts","4":"music_posts","5":"project_posts"}
    category = prefixs[id[0]]
    form = PostForm(MultiDict([("id", id),("title", data[category][str(id)]['title']) ,("date", data[category][str(id)]['date']),("content" , data[category][str(id)]['content'])]))


    if request.method == "POST":
        form.validate()
        data[category][str(id)] = {
            'id': str(id),
            'title': form.title.data,
            'date': form.date.data,
            'content': str(form.content.data)
        }
        all_posts[str(id)] = {
            'id': str(id),
            'title': form.title.data,
            'date': form.date.data,
            'content': str(form.content.data)
        }
        #Write to file.
        print('Saving the edited post..')
        with open(file_path_all, 'w') as file:
            json.dump(all_posts,file)
            print('File Saved ') 
        with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
            json.dump(data,file)
            flash('File Saved')
            return redirect('/')

    return render_template('edited_post.html', title="Post Editor", form = form)
if __name__ == '__main__':

    QFlask(app).run(title="Web Post Editor", zoom=0,  width=600, height= 600)
posteditor.html
    <html>
        <head><title> Post Editor</title>
            <style src="{{url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css')}}"></style>
            <style>
                pre{
                    content-align: left;
                }
                body{
                    color: grey;
                    background-image: url({{url_for('static', filename='img/editor-bg.jpg')}});
                }
            </style>
            <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
            <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/popper.js')}}"></script>
            <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <div class="container">
                    {% with message = get_flashed_messages()%}
                    <ul class="flashes">
                        {{message}}
                    </ul>
                    {% endwith%}
                    {{ form.csrf_token }}
                    <form method="POST" action="" id="selection">
                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                    {{edit_form.loadform.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                                    {{ edit_form.loadform(class="form-control form-control-lg")}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                    {{ edit_form.loadposts(class="btn btn-outline-info")}}
                            </div> 
                            </fieldset>
                    </form>
                    <form method="POST" action="">
                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                    {{ form.category.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                                    {{ form.category(class="form-control form-control-lg")}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                    {{ form.title.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                                    {{ form.title(class="form-control form-control-lg")}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                        {{ form.date.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                                        {{ form.date(class="form-control form-control-lg")}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                        {{ form.content.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                                        {{ form.content(cols="50", rows="20",class="form-control form-control-lg")}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                        {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                    </form>

                </div>
        </body>
    </html>
editedpost.html:

    <html>
        <head><title> Post Editor</title>
            <style src="{{url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css')}}"></style>
            <style>
                pre{
                    content-align: left;
                }
                body{
                    color: grey;
                    background-image: url({{url_for('static', filename='img/editor-bg.jpg')}});
                }
            </style>
            <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
            <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/popper.js')}}"></script>
            <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <div class="container">
                    {% with message = get_flashed_messages()%}
                    <ul class="flashes">
                        {{message}}
                    </ul>
                    {% endwith%}


                    <form method="POST" action="">
                            {{ form.csrf_token }}
                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                    {{ form.category.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                                    {{ form.category(class="form-control form-control-lg")}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                    {{ form.title.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                                    {{ form.title(class="form-control form-control-lg")}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                        {{ form.date.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                                        {{ form.date(class="form-control form-control-lg")}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                        {{ form.content.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                                        {{ form.content(cols="50", rows="20",class="form-control form-control-lg")}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                        {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                    </form>

                </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: PS - Qflask is bypassable (im running this as a standalone window (pyqt5)).. you can just set the env var  as  set FLASK_APP= filename. py ,   and set FLASK_DEBUG=1 ..  and then python -m flask run --host=127.0.0.1

Comment: I found the answer(with the help of some IRC folk ).The problem was the form data was always pulling from the initialized version. It never requested the update from the page.  in data[category][str(id)] = , the values should be updated via request.form.get('title') etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer(with the help of some IRC folk ).The problem was the form data was always pulling from the initialized version. It never requested the update from the page. in data[category][str(id)] = , the values should be updated via request.form.get('title')